# Remove duplicate question from Tagged Questions newest list

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, newest-questions

For the last several days I've been visiting the [newest question list on the C tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=newest&pageSize=50), and come across many questions marked as [duplicate]. After that I visited many other tags' questions and found the same thing -- many questions marked as [duplicate].

Why are these question not removed from the newest list? So, the views or importance should be given to new problems rather to old problems question which are already answered correctly.

Comment: Was it really needed to [cross post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280202/remove-duplicate-question-from-tagged-questions-newest-list)? Please remove one of the posts.

Comment: Doubt it will be removed, you can simply browse the resultsof adding an advanced search `closed:no` operator: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%5d%20closed%3ano